# Append separate .csv files to an existing .xlsx where the .xlsx is one directory above the current directory

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlsx

I want to append 4 .csv files to 4 existing sheets of the same name that are present in a separate excel, one directory above

Example:
A.csv, B.csv, C.csv, D.csv - these files sit in the current directory
.xlsx file that has sheets named: A, B, C, D - this file sits in the parent directory

Output:
.xlsx file should have the data from respective .csvs appended to the respective sheets

This is my code:

```
parent_directory = os.directory.absdirectory(os.directory.join(directory, os.pardir))
for filename in os.listdir(parent_directory):
   if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
       parent_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Dashboard Master Data.xlsx')
       pd.read_csv('a.csv').to_excel(writer,'a')
parent_writer.save()
```

Comment: Can you describe in detail the specific issue you're having in implementing this?

Comment: It wont append to the correct file - it instead creates a new excel in the current directory

Comment: Seems like you need to pass a full path to `ExcelWriter`.